# Linux Server - Windows Program

Tags: linux, cross-platform, web-server

I have a Linux server that I use to run php code. 
I was told that I had to integrate a windows server application (.exe and .vbs) and build a communication layer between them.
Which tool(s) would you recommend I install on the Linux server which would allow me to solve this issue.

Any direction would be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use https://www.winehq.org/ .

However, I would be careful to evaluate the specific program before committing to it. I may be easier to set up a separate windows server just for that (or use Windows to run both php and the windows server application)